Bold tag not applied to Chinese words correctly
For example, the bold tag isn't applied correctly. The following code should have the word 吃饭 in bold
我要**吃饭**啦

but instead it shows 吃饭 in italic with asterisks around the word. like this: 我要*吃饭*啦
If there is a space before and after the bold tag, then it works. The preview section when you enter the question also works correctly. This wouldn't be a problem for English which most of the SE sites are based in, but it would be a problem for East Asian language based sites.

It's not a bug. The **  thing is Markdown, and it works like that I think... Anyway, when you don't have space, such as an expression, use HTML:
我要<strong>吃饭</strong>啦

gives
我要吃饭啦
I've been told that "b" and "i" are getting used less and less (deprecated), so use the ones Yi Jiang suggested:
<strong>AAA</strong> = bold
<em>AAA</em> = emphasis

I don't remember other tags you might need... In case, just ask me in a comment. :)

ah, cool. Didn't realize you can use html.

Ehehe :D there should be a quick reference guide in the FAQ, if I remember well...

<strong> and <em> for bold and italics would probably be preferable, though there is no difference in the end result. Also note that comments and chat do not accept HTML, so this will remain a problem in these places.

@YiJiang易江 I updated my answer, it seems you were right. :)

@StarCub Answer updated!

A list of HTML tags you can use is available here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777

@Alenanno Since ** is not working for Chinese characters unless you manually enter spaces around it, should the script for the B button in the editor be replaced with  tag instead?

@StarCub I'm not sure I can answer this question, you should ask who takes care about such things. :D But I suppose they preferred using Markdown because it's much easier to use also for those who don't work with computers... I mean understanding ** is easier than knowing about tags, closing tags, etc... That's my supposition.

hmmm, but I thought tags like  are more human-friendly than ** and maybe easier to memorize?

Ahah the way you said it made me smile lol :D I'm not sure it's just a problem on here, so maybe someone already asked. Have you tried searching the meta Stackoverflow site?

This is now working:

我要吃饭啦

